# Connecting div elements using jQuery and LeaderLine

Tags: jquery

I would like to connect `div` elements via connectors on their right/left sides. These connectors are nothing else than a `div` with `class="entry-connector"` or `class="exit-connector"`, enclosing an `<a>` tag. I placed the `<a>` tag to be able to click on the element, since a `div` by itself is not clickable and hence, I thought it might not be able to incorporate it into a jQuery event handling such as: `$(".exit-connector").click(function(e){...}`.

On the container, there may be several elements and the user can decide which two to connect (see below image for an example with 4 such elements). My idea was to first implement a blinking functionality for the connector the user clicked on, signalling that the connector is active and  is waiting for a matching end-connection to be selected. And secondly, implement the actual connection between the two selected connectors: start and end.

For the first part, I set up a CSS animation that switches opacity between 0.5 and 1.0 in every second, and created a jQuery onclick listener like so:

```
$(".container").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clickedConnector = $(e.target);
    clickedConnector.classList.add("active-connector");
});
```

where the `active-connector` class contains the aforementioned CSS animation.

For the second part, I intended to use [LeaderLine](https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/) which was recommended in an older SO post already as being a versatile tool for connecting elements in JavaScript ([here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FP7Zy/1/)). My understanding is that if I manage to save references to the two clicked elements (i.e. start and end connectors), I can simply call the `.connections()` function to connect them. I wanted to use the aforementioned `active-connector` class to do so:

```
$(".active-connector").connections();
```

Unfortunately, none of my approaches seem to produce any results. The connectors I created are clickable, but nothing happens upon clicking (animation doesn't start). I assume that the `"active-connector"` class might not get added to the clicked element and hence, LeaderLine cannot identify the elements to connect either.

Full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".exit-create").click(function(e) {
    $(".container").append('<div class="indi-box"><div>Indicator</div><form><select id="dropdown"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></form><a href="#" class="exit-connector"></a></div>');
    $(".indi-box").draggable({
      constraint: ".container",
      containment: "parent"
    });
  });
  $(".entry-create").click(function(e) {
    $(".container").append('<div class="indi-box"><div>Indicator</div><form><select id="dropdown"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></form><a href="#" class="entry-connector"></a></div>');
    $(".indi-box").draggable({
      constraint: ".container",
      containment: "parent"
    });
  });
  //$(".indi-box").click(function(e) {
  //  var clickedConnector = $(e.target);
  //  clickedConnector.classList.add("active-connector");
  //});

  //$(".active-connector").connections();

});
```

```css
  #dropdown {
  margin: 2em;
}

.container {
  height: 50vw;
  width: 90vw;
  background-color: powderblue;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.indi-box {
  background-color: #336DFF;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.entry-connector {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 12px;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

.exit-connector {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 12px;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
}

.active-connector {
  -webkit-animation: CONNECTOR-ACTIVE 1s infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: CONNECTOR-ACTIVE 1s infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: CONNECTOR-ACTIVE 1s infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: CONNECTOR-ACTIVE 1s infinite;
  /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}

@-webkit-keyframes CONNECTOR-ACTIVE {
  0%,
  49% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anseki/leader-line/master/leader-line.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="exit-create">Create Exit Indi</button>
  <button class="entry-create">Create Entry Indi</button>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

[image: A sample application: the user can decide which two boxes to connect via the connectors on the left/right]

Comment: I tried to make you a snippet. It did not work.

Comment: I don't know why the code doesn't run here @mplungjan, if that's what you meant. I copypasted my HTML, CSS, and JS snippets very carefully. I now double-checked and it runs on Atom.
Edit: tried commenting out the potentially problematic parts of the JS code, assuming that that might be the reason SO can't run it. Not the case.

Comment: @mplungjan it seems to work now, although takes a bit of time on my side. I commented out a section of the JS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your `indi-box` are dynamically created so you need to bind it with some static elements so change that i.e : `$(".container").on("click", ".indi-box", function(e) {..})` .

Next , there are two of divs i.e : entry and exit . Now  , user should select **entry** div first so you can check if the div which is clicked is entry or not and if there are any other entry div which is already selected depending on this add your class to entry div else show some messages(alert).

Lastly , user can click exit div first as well so you can check if there is any entry div selected or not so depending on this show some messages(alert) else just use the `id` of entry and exit div and pass that inside `new LeaderLine(here..)`  to make connections between them.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".exit-create").click(function(e) {
    var length = $(".indi-box").length + 1
    $(".container").append('<div class="indi-box" id="exit_' + length + '"><div>Indicator</div><form><select id="dropdown"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></form><a href="#" class="exit-connector"></a></div>');
    $(".indi-box").draggable({
      constraint: ".container",
      containment: "parent"
    });
  });
  $(".entry-create").click(function(e) {
    var length = $(".indi-box").length + 1
    $(".container").append('<div class="indi-box" id="entry_' + length + '"><div>Indicator</div><form><select id="dropdown"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></form><a href="#" class="entry-connector"></a></div>');
    $(".indi-box").draggable({
      constraint: ".container",
      containment: "parent"
    });
  });
  //onclick of indi-box
  $(".container").on("click", ".indi-box", function(e) {
    //check if the div which is clicked has entry connctr
    if ($(this).find(".entry-connector").length > 0) {
      if ($(".active-connector").length == 0) {
        $(this).toggleClass("active-connector"); //add class there
      } else {
        alert("You have already selected one entry please select exit for it")
      }
    } else {
      //check if already one entry is selected
      if ($(".active-connector").length > 0) {
        var start = $(".active-connector").attr('id')
        //make connections
        new LeaderLine($('#' + start)[0], $('#' + $(this).attr("id"))[0])
        $(".indi-box").removeClass("active-connector") //removed class
      } else {
        alert("Please select entry first")
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
  #dropdown {
  margin: 2em;
}

.container {
  height: 50vw;
  width: 90vw;
  background-color: powderblue;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.indi-box {
  background-color: #336DFF;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.entry-connector {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 12px;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

.exit-connector {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 12px;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
}

.active-connector {
  -webkit-animation: CONNECTOR-ACTIVE 1s infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: CONNECTOR-ACTIVE 1s infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: CONNECTOR-ACTIVE 1s infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: CONNECTOR-ACTIVE 1s infinite;
  /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}

@-webkit-keyframes CONNECTOR-ACTIVE {
  0%,
  49% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leader-line@1.0.5/leader-line.min.js"></script>

<button class="exit-create">Create Exit Indi</button>
<button class="entry-create">Create Entry Indi</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent solution, @Swati, thanks a lot! However, I noticed that when dragging the boxes, the connecting lines don't move along. Obviously, adding a `.draggable()` to the `new LeaderLine(...)` declaration isn't the solution either since that would make the line draggable independently from the boxes. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: No, I will think about this and let you know if i found something :)